# How SpringBoot works on application servers

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on migrating our Spring REST applications to Spring Boot microservices. I have some doubt:

As I know spring boot has a `main()` and it calls static `run()` which is present in SpringApplication. So, when we run it as "Java Applicaton" in Eclipse IDE, this `main()` gets called and `@SpringBootApplication` annotation do the magic. But when I deploy this application on Websphere Application Servers, then how is this working because now the `main()` will not gets called. Then how all the beans getting loaded without calling the `main()`.

Comment: WAS servers - do you mean Windows Service ?

Comment: Websphere application server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot implicitely starts an embedded server, which is included in `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency. That's why `main()` method works in boot environment.

Typical solution is to create two profiles - one for boot development and the other for deployment - then you may have several starting points.

Dev config:

```
@Configuration
@Profile(Profiles.DEV)
@Import(AppConfig.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
            .profiles(Profiles.DEV)
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

Deploy config (for WAS, tomcat, ...):

```
@Configuration
@Profile(Profiles.DEPLOY)
@Import(AppConfig.class)
public class ApplicationTomcat extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application
            .profiles(Profiles.DEPLOY)
            .sources(ApplicationTomcat.class);
    }
}
```

Profiles:

```
public class Profiles {

    public final static String DEV = "dev";

    public final static String DEPLOY = "deploy";
}
```

In your deployment profile, don't forget to exclude `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency and make it `war` bundle.

This way you can deploy application on WAS (or tomcat, ...) in standard way and start your application localy also with `main()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your input but still one doubt. How WAS server is getting to know whether this application is SpringBoot or not as there is no web.xml no dispatcher servlet. Also,as you said Spring boot starts an embedded server, when we deploy the application on WAS, then how SpringBoot works and loads the beans. as that time it will not run main() where annotation is present?

Comment: This is a dominant of `spring-boot-gradle-plugin` or `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. Both of these repackage the application under the hood and all you need is to specify jar/war output. You can learn more about these plugins [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/). i posted the solution how to get info about actual deployment in code, so you can conditionally specify beans etc.

Comment: Thanks your your input. I am aware how to deploy WAR in WAS by using Maven/Gradle. But still not able to figure out WAS loading the spring beans in its container as main() not getting called once we deploy and run WAR in WAS.