# How to deploy a reactive ( netty) on an application server (weblogic in my case)?

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic, spring-webflux, project-reactor, rsocket

By looking around (example [How SpringBoot works on application servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51870138/how-springboot-works-on-application-servers)) it is very easy to move a springboot rest application (thus using spring-boot-starter-web) on an application server because, I think, in the end they all have a tomcat server under the hood.

But what can I do to deploy a spring-boot-starter-webflux or, even better, a spring-boot-starter-rsocket that make use of the netty container? Isn't it just not possible or is there some way to make it work?

Comment: Technically, it should be possible if you bundle your application as war. Container needs to support servlet 3.1+. I haven't tried it yet but I would start by extending `AbstractReactiveWebInitializer`. All in all, this requirement doesn't make sense to me as everybody is switching to micro services.

Comment: Unfortunately, as in my case, there is still a transiction period :(